# I want to change the screen in the dart code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

```
 class Spiel_nummer {
  Random random = new Random();
  int trys = 5;
  int random_number = 0;
  int lastguess = 0;
  dynamic ico = null;
  int score = 0;
  int generate_random_number() => random.nextInt(101);

  bool guessnumber(int number) {
    print(number);
    if (number == random_number) {
      reset();
      score++;
      return true;
    } else {
      trys--;
      if (number < random_number) {
        lastguess = 0;
        ico = Icons.arrow_upward;
      } else if (number > random_number) {
        lastguess = 1;
        ico = Icons.arrow_downward;
      }
      if (trys <= 0) {         
        gameover();
        score = 0;
        reset();
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
  void gameover(){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()));
  } 
}
```

I want to change the screen to game over when the trys variable gets lower than 1.

I get this error every time:

[image]

> The error says that I have to use an argument of the type BuildContext.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error, you've imported `import 'dart:js';` on `gameover()`. remove this import and pass `Buildcontext` to the method like

```dart
void gameover(BuildContext context) {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()));
}
```

This context will import from `material.dart`, `cupertino.dart` or `widgets.dart` by default .

Comment: But then I get the same error when I call the function.

Comment: did you recheck the import section?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it

Comment: is it possible it is coming from other place?